# where to put constant used in a java class?

Tags: java

I would like to know where to put constants which is only used in one java class? My code creates a name for a shared memory says "sharedMemory" , but I am not sure if I should put in separate Java file or just define in the same class as private static final String SHARED_MEMORY = "sharedMemory". **I need this variable only in specific class. Also,if i define in same class should i make it static?**

```
class ABC{

private static final String SHARED_MEMORY = "sharedMemory"; // OK to define in same class or in separate constants file

   public void get(){
   String name;
    if(checIfSharedMemoryNeeded()){
      name  = SHARED_MEMORY;
    }
   }

   private boolen checIfSharedMemoryNeeded(){
     return (x.equals("yuiyr") && y.equals("yweir"))
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you need that constant only in that specific class? If yes, it should be private (as it is) and then it will be in the right place.

Comment: You need it in only this class, as a result, it's fine where it is.

Comment: is it necessary to make it static?

Comment: @Reena necessary, no, but it avoids using resources of your system that you don't need. why would you create the variable for every instance, if it has to be the same for every instance?

Comment: @Stultuske - i still dont follow, if static is necessary here/

Comment: @Reena What Stultuske means to say: it is not necessary, but better, because less resource-intensive.

Comment: @Reena - I am seeing a pattern in your recent questions.  I think you should stop.  These are all opinion-based.  If you want to understand good style, please read a Java style guide.

Answer (score 1):

Define constants that you only need in a single class in that class and make them `private`. You can make sure it will not accidentally be used anywhere else.

```
private static final String ONLY_FOR_THIS_CLASS = "only here";
```

Define constants that are contextually bound to a specific class but may be needed in other classes in that class they are contextually bound to, but make them `public`.

```
public static final String CONTEXTUALLY_FOR_THIS_CLASS_BUT_USABLE_ANYWHERE = "everywhere";
```

It will allow the usage in other classes like

```
String constantValueFromOtherClass = OtherClass.CONTEXTUALLY_FOR_THIS_CLASS_BUT_USABLE_ANYWHERE;
```

Think about writing an `enum` if the idea of a class that only holds public constants comes to your mind. In many cases, `enum`s will be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are no common guidelines for what to do. Since it only used at one place, I recommend you to leave it in the class where it is used.

Unless you want to change the value in the future and you have many other hardcoded values that you want to change later, then I recommend that you make a class Config that holds all these values.

Comment: "unless you want to change the value in the future". why would that matter? the restriction is not on what value it has, but where it is used.

Comment: In large projects, it can become difficult to get an overview of all these kind of values. They will often not stay constant. Consider this case: You have a game. The NPCs have hardcoded dialog. A specific line will only be used one place in the code, but other lines will be used elsewhere. It will be difficult to keep an overview of all the dialog if they are all in separate classes. Besides, consider if you want to support different languages. Then you can have a EnglishDialog class and a FrenchDialog class.

Comment: either they keep the same value, or they aren't constants.

Comment: They are constants when compiled, but the code can always change.

Comment: NPC dialog is a bad example as it's not a use case for constants but rather some kind of message source pattern.

Comment: I believe that a game is easy to relate to, and it was the best that I could come up with. Can you recommend a better example?

Comment: The most primitive example used to introduce constants is probably arrays. Instead of using a "magic number" `new int[5]`, you use a constant `new int[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS]`.

Comment: I also have to disagree with your statement on there being no common guidelines. There *are* common guidelines; it's not like this issue is uncovered ground after 23 years of Java. See deHaar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this constant is only used for this class, then you should declare are the same class scope.

Now you gotta think if you are going to change the value in the future. If you do, and your application scales, it is better to create a .properties file to hold all the values and load to your app.

Answer (score 0):

The general convention for non-global constants in Java is to write it with `private static final` like so:

```
class Foo {
    private static final String bar = "foobar";

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this variable (SHARED_MEMORY) in ABC class then private access specifier is okay, and if this variable is part of your class not object then using static is a good idea.